# Generating a random variable with kernel $f(x)\propto x^a\exp\{-bx^2-cx\}$.

Tags: bayesian, sampling, simulation

I came across this denisty when designing a Gibbs sampler. This doesn't seem like a well-defined or common distribution. Is there any way to efficiently sample from this exact distribution?